# How to active profile as environment variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I was configuring environment variables using spring profiles in my spring boot application. There i did configuration like

My interface is

```
public interface EnvConfiguration {

    String getServerUrl();

}
```

My development configuration is

```
@Component
    public class DevelopmentConfig implements EnvConfiguration{

        @Value("${DEV}")
        private String serverUrl;

        @Override
        public String getServerUrl(){
            return serverUrl;
        }
    }

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevelopmentProfile {

    @Bean
    public EnvConfiguration getDevelopmentConfig(){
        return new DevelopmentConfig();
    }
}
```

Same as i did configured for production environment

```
@Component
public class ProductionConfig implements EnvConfiguration {

    @Value("${PROD}")
    private String serverUrl;

    @Override
    public String getServerUrl(){
        return serverUrl;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProductionProfile {

    @Bean
    public EnvConfiguration getProductionConfig(){
        return new ProductionConfig();
    }
}
```

Now i configured environment variable in eclipse using run configurations->agruments

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

[image: Bootstrap application]

Now when i trying to run my application,i am getting error:

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: productionConfig,developmentConfig
```

So please help me what am i missing there ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't annotate `DevelopmentConfig` and `ProductionConfig` with `@Component`. These are both exposed as Spring beans via `@Bean` in `DevelopmentProfile` and `ProductionProfile` respectively

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,but still it is not working,getting error "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency",i am autowiring using @autowired EnvConfiguration in my class

Comment: How do you bootstrap your Spring container?

Comment: Please check out this, i added screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was adding programming arguments,we have to add vm arguments

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to configure environment properties with Java ?

You could put all your configuration into an application.properties.
Then if you want dev environment, you juste override the properties you want in application-dev.properties.

The same for prod in application-prod.properties.

Then you start as you did with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev and you will be able to retrieve value with @Value.

Comment: i am using spring profile to configure that,there are two ways to to do that